# convert a \newcommand to \newenvironment

Tags: macros, environments

I have defined a command as follows

```
\newsavebox{\textsix}

\newcommand{\bottomr}[1]{\sbox{\textsix}{\parbox{11cm}{\begin{flushright} #1
\end{flushright}}}}
```

which save the parameter (text) of the command  `\bottomr` to a `\sbox`, That can be used with `\usebox{\textsix}`

I would like to convert it to an environment like

```
\newsavebox{\textsix}
\newenvironment{bottomr}{ }{ }
```

which capture the text inside `bottomr`  environment and save it to a `\sbox` Approximate like this

```
\documentclass[a4paper{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\newsavebox{\textsix}
\newenvironment{bottomr}{?}{?}
\begin{bottomr}
\lipsum[1]
\end{bottomr}

\usebox{\textsix}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Seems that `environ` package should be able to do what you want.

Comment: Related: [Can this command be converted to environment?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7769/5764); [How can I collect the contents of a LaTeX environment in a macro without the grouping?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/116032/5764)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The environment form of `\sbox` is environment `lrbox`. Environment `minipage` can be used instead of the command `\parbox`. Environment `flushright` is not necessary, because there is the command form `\raggedleft`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\newsavebox{\textsix}

\newenvironment{bottomr}{%
  \begin{lrbox}{\textsix}%
  \begin{minipage}{11cm}%
  \raggedleft
}{%
  \end{minipage}%
  \end{lrbox}%
  % export box register setting outside the scope of the environment
  \global\setbox\textsix=\copy\textsix
}
\begin{bottomr}
\lipsum[1]
\end{bottomr}

\usebox{\textsix}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Answer (score 3):

Following some guidelines from [How can I collect the contents of a LaTeX environment in a macro without the grouping?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/116032/5764), here is an [`environ`](http://ctan.org/pkg/environ) approach:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,environ}

\newsavebox{\textsix}
\NewEnviron{bottomr}[1][11cm]{%
  \expandafter\gdef\expandafter\envBODY\expandafter{\BODY}% Store body
  \gdef\dolaterbottomr{\savebox\textsix{\parbox{#1}{\raggedleft\strut\envBODY\strut}}}
  \aftergroup\dolaterbottomr%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{bottomr}
\lipsum*[2]
\end{bottomr}

\lipsum*[1]\strut

\usebox{\textsix}

\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

I've added an optional argument specifying the width of the `\parbox` (default is `11cm`), as well as some `\strut`s to manage baselines at the start/end of paragraph(s). I don't know whether this is necessary.